# Arduino Long distance cable tester

Tags: arduino

We have a 50 pair cable running about 1.5-2 KM with some services running on different pairs. One pair has recently become intermittent and is losing connection for  1-2 seconds at random. It might happen a few times an hour, so I jumped the service onto another pair. There is a modem connected to the pair for communication between two sites.

When resistance tested with a multi meter with a loop in one end it was reading 330 Ohms. When using an oscar meter it was reading -2.4db which is the same readings for other pairs.

I would like to use an Arduino to monitor the line resistance for a few days and see if there are any spikes or breaks in the line. 
I was going to use an analog input as a multimeter by using a known resistor and the looped pair as the other resistor.
[As seen here.](http://www.circuitbasics.com/arduino-ohm-meter/)

Does anybody think this will not work?

How else could I go about this?

Comment: [Arduino SE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

What you plan should work.  I'd log the data to a PC with a timestamp.  You can then analyse the measurements later to see if the disturbances occur at a particular time of day.